# Is there a way to get better antialiasing with scipy zoom

Tags: python, image, scipy

I'm making a mouse tracking script, and I just tried writing my own resampling since I want the output to merge all recorded resolutions, but I couldn't iron out some bugs so gave up and tried out scipy for it.

It almost works perfectly, but it looks bad at the same time, especially if making an image smaller. I thought this might be normal until I saw the result from PIL, which was pretty much perfect, just unfortunately by that time it's too late to merge the arrays.

For the record, `new_data` is in the format `[[(x0, y0), (x1, y0)],[(x1, y0),...`. Originally it's in a dictionary where each coordinate is a key (but I don't think that can be made into a numpy array).

Here's downscaling using scipy:

```
zoom_factor = (desired_resolution[0] / current_resolution[0],
               desired_resolution[1] / current_resolution[1])
numpy_image = zoom(np.array(new_data), zoom_factor, order=1)
```

[image]

Here's using PIL:

```
im = im.resize(desired_resolution, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

[image]

As you can see, PIL is a lot smoother. The only suggestion I can think of currently is to use scipy to upscale to the largest resolution, then use PIL to downscale again, but it seems messy. If anyone has another idea please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that upscaling with scipy, combining then converting to RGB, then downscaling with PIL, is exactly what was needed.

The upscaling was done to 4k, though it still looked almost the same (just slightly more jagged) at 1080p. From the list of 4k arrays, I could then combine the results by getting the maximum value and converting it to it's colour value. From that point it's as simple as feeding it into PIL and telling it to resize to something smaller.

Here is the result with a combined 2560x1440 and 800x600 tracks (saved at 720p):
[image]

Obviously the size difference can't really be helped as I'm not storing vectors or anything, but it does demonstrate how it deals with multiple resolutions combined.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but this looks like a cool project. Do you have a public repository of your code by any chance?

Comment: Thanks haha, and sure, it's a bit of a mess but here - https://github.com/Peter92/MouseTrack. If you want to try it, I think the main script only needs `win32api`, then just check the imports for the image generation :)

Comment: Cheers. I am on linux so I might look into porting it. ;-)

Comment: I've put everything windows related into `_track_windows.py` (and it's not much) so it's easy to see what needs to be replaced. If you manage to get it working though, I'd be super grateful if you could send it back and I'll work it into the main thing haha :P

Comment: You will get a pull request when I am there, no worries. ;-)

Comment: Just remembered about your comment haha, someone else has almost fully ported it to linux if you're wanting to try it out :p

Comment: Definitely. Glad somebody else picked up my slack -- I am still stuck on the corrections for my PhD thesis (which unfortunately have a higher priority than porting cool projects like this one). I like the reddit post, btw.

Comment: Haha, normally I'd be surprised you came across it, but the interest was pretty insane (I'd have actually finished it first if I had any idea lol). Good luck with the phd though, and I guess at least it's considerably more productive than porting stuff :)